# Locating a Notary Public in Cozumel Mexico

Tags: legal, cozumel

I need to locate a Notary Public on Cozumel Island, Mexico. This is needed to have a legal document signed under witness recognised in Australia.

Does anyone know how to search for one, or the name of one?

Answer (score 2):

I searched google for *notarios mexico* and the first hit is [Directorio de notarios](http://www.notarios.com.mx). You have to select the state (Cozumel belongs to *Quintana Roos* state) and the city (obviously Cozumel) and you get 3 notarios:

1. BELLO MELCHOR RODRIGUEZ CARRILLO (#4). 
   CALLE 11 SUR NO.885
   ADOLFO LOPEZ MATEOS, COZUMEL
2. JOSE EDWIN VILLANUEVA MARRUFO (#15). 55 AVENIDA BIS, NO. 436, ENTRE CALLE 8 Y 10, 10 DE ABRIL, COZUMEL
3. MANUEL IRVIN GARCIA VALDEZ (#9) AV. 20 NORTE CON AV. JUAREZ NO. 1 CENTRO, COZUMEL

Answer (score 1):

A [quick Google search for "cozumel notary"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=cozumel+notary) shows us a couple of results.  Careful to avoid the Cozumel in Canada when you look...but otherwise:

[Notaria on Directoriolocal.com](http://www.directoriolocal.com/cozumel/c/notaries/):

- **Notaría Pública 15**
  Cozumel, Quintana Roo
  Av. 5ta Norte Desp. No. 298 Col. Centro
  (987)
  872-4033
- **Notaria Publica No.72**
  Cozumel, Quintana Roo
  Calle 8 Norte No. 5 X 15 Av. Cozumel
  (987)
  872-7420 / 872-2846